# Can I randomly sample 10 columns when you use head()?

Tags: r

When there are many columns head() function does not skip any of them and this creates complications. head(df,10) could reduce the number of rows, however, when there are 100 columns head() does not work properly and the outcome is very complicated. Can I randomly sample 10 columns, for example?

Comment: Maybe subset columns, too? `head(df[, 1:10], 10)`

Comment: Or `df[1:10, 1:10]`

Comment: perfect, I believe this will work.  Many thanks!

Comment: See the linked post for more options.

Comment: You could also convert the df into a tibble. The output fits snuggly into the window.

Comment: How can I convert it into a tibble, if I may ask??

Comment: With the 'tibble' function from the package of the same name.

Comment: See if package [peep](https://github.com/romunov/peep) would fit your need. Disclaimer, I'm the author of the package.